# Generic formula for polynomial expansion

Tags: polynomials, roots

*Short version*: Is there a generic formula for a polynomial expansion of the form $\prod_i{(x-p_i)}$?

*Long version*: I need to verify finding the roots of polynomials (C++), and, while I could do it by simply evaluating at a point, or more, I'd like to have the polynomial expanded, to collect the terms. The $p_i$ terms are complex conjugate roots (all negative real part, if that matters), and if the order N is odd, there's an additional negative real root.

Currently, I am storing each root as a vector of 2 complex values (all inside another vector of length N), with the terms of $x-p_i$: $\left[[1, p_0], [1, p_1], ...\right]$. For expansion I am convolving the 1st with the 2nd, store the result in a length 3 vector, backup this vector in order to be reused for the next convolution, which needs to resize the vector, then repeat the process. This makes me cringe, but it works, eventually. However, I'd like to know if there's a more humane way of doing this.

Comment: The best method depends on the exact goal. What is exactly what you need to do? Evaluate the polynomial at a single $x$, at many $x$, compute the coefficients once, compute them for many options of $p_i$s? There are formulas for the coefficients in terms of the roots. They are called Vieta's formulas. However, very likely you shouldn't use them because they are slow and can accumulate a lot of numerical error when you evaluate them.

Comment: You said that you want to verify finding roots. Does that mean that you already have the coefficients of the polynomial? Given the coefficients, one of the best ways to evaluate a polynomial is [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). Note that if the coefficients are real and you verify, by evaluating the polynomial, that a complex root $p_i$ is a root, then you don't need to verify that the conjugate of $p_i$ is also a root.

Comment: I need to verify the roots, which I already have them, calculated from a polynomial. In order to verify the original polynomial, I need to expand the product of the roots, to re-form the polynomial and collect the terms (for comparison).

Comment: The goal of verifying the roots doesn't demand expanding the product of the roots, as you call it. As I said, if you have the polynomial's original coefficients, and you have the computed roots, then you can best verify that they are roots, by evaluating the polynomial. Vieta's formulas require a lot of operations to evaluate, and can produce huge numerical errors.

Comment: @flan True, but it's one thing to display a single number and say "the evaluation is a success", and another to display, side by side, the original and the reconstructed polynomial. Admittedly, it's a bit of a whim (and, as I mentioned, I could do it), but presentation also matters.

Comment: If you want the coefficients implied by the roots, you can do the following: Note that $a_0$, the constant term is just $f(0)$. So, you have a sequence of interpolating points $(x,f(x))=(p_1,0),(p_2,0),...(p_N,0)$ and require the interpolated value $f(0)$. A good algorithm to compute this is [Neville's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm). The remaining coefficients are also values at $0$ of derivatives of $f$. Namely $f^{(n)}(0)/n!$. There are interpolating algorithms to compute these too. Let me see if I find a reference to them.

Comment: Ah, well. I don't have an explicit reference. But look at Neville's algorithm carefully. Think of it with the $x_i$ as the roots $p_i$, the $y_i$ are all $0$, but the $x$, instead of a specific value, as a symbol. Compute at each step the coefficients of each of the $p_{i,j}(x)$ and from them the coefficients of the next row. It gives you an algorithm of about $N^2$ steps. Using Fast Fourier Transform it should be possible to drop this down to $N\log(N)$.

Comment: Ah, in Introduction to Algorithms, by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein, they have it in Chapter 30. Note that what you have is 'point value form' and you need to get to 'coefficient form'. They explain there how to do this using inverse discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: @flan Then the convolution way I use is just fine, since I use it as `ifft( fft(a) * fft(b) )`, without interpolation. :-) Thank you for the suggestions, they're just as valid as Eric Wofsey's answer, but, just as in the comment to his answer, this turned out to be another one of those "if it ain't broken..." answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: you can expand the whole thing at once using the $N$-ary distributive law, which says that an $N$-ary product of sums is the sum of all the $N$-ary products you can get from choosing one term from each of the sums.  This means that $\prod_{i=0}^{N-1}(x-p_i)$ expands as as sum of $2^N$ terms, one for each way to choose either $x$ or $-p_i$ from each factor.  Grouping the terms according to the power of $x$, this means that the coefficient of $x^k$ is the sum of all products of $N-k$ different choices of $-p_i$, also known as the $(N-k)$th elementary symmetric polynomial in the $-p_i$.  To be explicit, the expansion is $$\prod_{i=0}^{N-1}(x-p_i)=\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^{N-k}\left(\sum_{0\leq i_1<i_2<\dots<i_{N-k}\leq N-1}\prod_{j=1}^{N-k}p_{i_j}\right)x^k$$ (the factor of $(-1)^{N-k}$ coming from pulling out the $-1$ from each $-p_{i_j}$).  For instance, when $N=4$, you get $$x^4-(p_0+p_1+p_2+p_3)x^3+(p_0p_1+p_0p_2+p_0p_3+p_1p_2+p_1p_3+p_2p_3)x^2-(p_0p_1p_2+p_0p_1p_3+p_0p_2p_3+p_1p_2p_3)x+p_0p_1p_2p_3.$$

I suspect, though, that your method of iteratively multiplying the factors one by one is more computationally efficient than trying to use this full expansion directly, since it should cut down on the number of separate multiplications you have to do (you don't want to have to separately multiply the $p_i$ together for each of $2^N$ different terms!).

Comment: I tried manually checking symbolic expansions with wxMaxima, and even as low as N=4 (the example I see in your answer, too), the results scared me: there are so many multiplications in there that could, no doubt, bury any problems of having to resize and copy the vectors. And if those wouldn't cause problems, the risk of overflow surely would. Still, this does answer my question, so Ill mark this and go home with yet another case of "be careful what you wish for"...